# Highcharts clipping or cutting off outermost bars in a bar chart. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have an app that uses Highcharts and several other components and the app is used, among many other things, to produce bar charts. Users can select time ranges against which they view data. One of the templates that we've put together does a side by side comparison and when the user chooses a short'ish timespan, the chart is cut off at the outside edges. I've looked at overflow and some other CSS solutions but this one just continues to perplex. When the app is looking a longer time ranges, it has no issue squeezing & adjusting to accommodate[image: example of the leftmost & rightmost bars being cut off]. But when the app tries to render shorter periods - like quarter by quarter - the result is that the outermost bars are cut off.

I included a screenshot. Does this look like anything that anybody has seen. And if so... any ideas on how to tackle it? The page template is liquid/responsive/elastic and should be able to accommodate this. Going further, Highcharts seems to do well in other areas where the width is elastic so I am wondering why this thing doesn't seem to be able to detect its own width and display the bars without cutting off.
If anyone has any ideas about this, I'd love to hear about it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: We're going to need to see some code in this case.

Comment: Try with `chart.reflow()`

Comment: Adding chart config is necessary in this case. Maybe you have some errors in JS console? Your data should be sorted ascending by x-values, if it's not then you have the reason. Maybe you have `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max` set which are wrong? You see, there may be many reasons. Live demo (with static data) would be great.

Comment: Looks like a potential issue with `pointRange`, or possibly an issue of the axis extremes being set incorrectly. But we'll need to see code or a working example to get an actual answer.